# Get ToDate , FromDate from Week Number in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I easily get Week Number using MySql `Week` function like this `WEEK(SYSDATE())`

I just wanted to know how to get `from and to date` using week number in MySQL.

Result required:

```
Week No From date       To date 
Week 25 June 18, 2012   June 24, 2012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works great for this kind of job:

```
SELECT
  ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY) _From,
  ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7-DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY) _To;
```

Beware that first day of week here is Sunday. It may depends on your country convention ;)

Comment: Be careful when you use this _To date as one end of a SELECT range: a DATE, when compared to a DATETIME, is the very first moment of the day in question.